# How to handle gearman worker, fatal error

Tags: php, zend-framework, gearman

I am having trouble handling gearman worker, fatal error. Gearman daemon stops on php fatal error.

I found on this url http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/handling-exceptions-in-gearman-tasks-even-background-ones/ solution but it is not working for me. This is my gearman worker cod:

```
$task = "send_lead";

$gmw->addFunction("sending_lead", function() use($task) {
    try {
        $result = call_user_func_array($task, func_get_args());
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        $result = GEARMAN_WORK_EXCEPTION;
        echo "Gearman: CAUGHT EXCEPTION: " . $e->getMessage();

        // Send exception to Exceptional so it can be logged with details
        Exceptional::handle_exception($e, FALSE);
    }

    return $result;
});
while(1)
  $gmw->work();
function send_lead($job)
{
 $send_lead = new Frontend_Model_Index();
  $send_lead->lead(json_decode($job->workload()));

}
```

Btw I am using zend 1.1.

**Update**

---

Error is  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSource_state() on a non-object in.

And that is ok error. But how to handle that error. I do not want deamon to be terminated becasue of any error, fatal or not.

Comment: I am talking about 500 error.

Comment: It would help if you pasted the description of the 500 error showing up in the server logs.

Comment: @Rolando Isidoro - I have updated question with error.